Efficiently wrap trivial types in swig
Suppose I have a very lightweight type in C++, eg:
/// Represents UTC timestamp
class Timestamp {
    int64_t nanos_;

    public:
    Timestamp(int64_t nanos)
        : nanos_(nanos) {}

    int64_t nanos() const noexcept { return nanos_; }

    /// Convert timestamp to stirng with form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (UTC time)
    std::string toString() const;

    /// Convert timestamp to stirng with form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (UTC time)
    /// Use the specified timezone, eg 'America/New_York
    std::string toString(std::string const& tz) const;

    // Other functions...
};

This type is effectively a wrapper for an int64_t, but it's a very useful wrapper. It exposes a ton of functionality for dealing with and manipulating timestamps.
I want this class to be made available in swig, but I also want it to be represented in an efficient manner.
In C++, this is a trivially copyable class. There's no overhead to using it, when compared to raw operations on an int64_t, and manipulating large vectors of timestamps is trivial.
The generated swig wrapper is so much heaver by comparison! Every single instance of a Timestamp in C# carries a pointer to a separate C++ timestamp, allocated on the heap, and every single function call involves multiple levels of indirection!
///  Represents UTC timestamp

public class Timestamp : global::System.IDisposable {
  private global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef swigCPtr;
  protected bool swigCMemOwn;

  internal Timestamp(global::System.IntPtr cPtr, bool cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(this, cPtr);
  }

  internal static global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef getCPtr(Timestamp obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(null, global::System.IntPtr.Zero) : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  internal static global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef swigRelease(Timestamp obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
      if (!obj.swigCMemOwn)
        throw new global::System.ApplicationException("Cannot release ownership as memory is not owned");
      global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef ptr = obj.swigCPtr;
      obj.swigCMemOwn = false;
      obj.Dispose();
      return ptr;
    } else {
      return new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(null, global::System.IntPtr.Zero);
    }
  }

  // ...

Is there any way to convince swig to create something equally efficient in C# (eg, a value-type wrapper over a int64?)

With SWIG the way it is right now I think you're stuck defining your own %typemap that uses a value type in C# instead of a reference type (class). Fortunately it shouldn't be too difficult since you can start with what it has already generated.
